# Connect via https and download file ionic3

Tags: angular, ionic3, file-transfer

Is that a way to connect to a server via https and download a file. I'm using [File Transfer](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/) but I can't authenticate. (Using wget I can access)

This is what a try :

```
let url = "https://0.0.0.0:0000/maps/"+element['file'];
                  this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
                  this.fileTransfer.download(url, res.nativeURL+""+element['file']).then((entry) => {
                    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
                  }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                  });
```

The url is not my real url, just to show you. Any idea?
I have to put username and password. Like for api in header append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Ionic 3 docs you can use headers with the download function.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/#download

> `download(source, target, trustAllHosts, Optional)`
>
> **Param** | **Type** | **Details**
>
> `Optional` |  `object` | parameters, currently only supports headers
>   (such as Authorization (Basic Authentication), etc).

Example:

```
let options = {
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
    }
}

this.fileTransfer.download(url, res.nativeURL + "" + element['file'], false, options).then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
}, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, have you an example? I don't know how to create this object.

Comment: I did this:  let headers: Headers = new Headers();
              headers.append("Authorization" , this.authHeaderValue(user, 'pass'));
              headers.append('Content-Type','image/svg+xml');

Comment: The error gives me : java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Is there a way to bypass it?

Comment: That's an other error from the server/backend, what kind of server/backend do you use? Maybe this is better for a new question, because it is java and not javascript